# Listview play two audio files on button click

Tags: android, listview, audio

I have a list view set up as below, each row has a 'play' button, what I need to achieve is having the mediaplayer play two audio files (one after the other) on the click of this play button.

```
public class WordsActivity extends SherlockActivity{
    Category currentCat;
    ArrayList<Word> words;
    String catID;
    MediaPlayer m;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        words = myDbHelper.getAllWordsforCat(catID);
        wordListAdapter adapter = new wordListAdapter(this, words);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.words_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    ...

    public class wordListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word>{

        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<Word> itemsArrayList;

        public wordListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> itemsArrayList) {

            super(context, R.layout.words_row, itemsArrayList);

            this.context = context;
            this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final Word word = itemsArrayList.get(position);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.words_row, parent, false);

            ...
            ImageView playbtn = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.word_play_btn);
            playbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    playfile(word.getengSound());
                }
            });

            ...

            return rowView;
        }

        public void playfile(String filename) {
            try {
                if (m.isPlaying()) {
                    m.stop();
                    m.release();
                    m = new MediaPlayer();
                }
                m = new MediaPlayer();
                AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd(filename);
                m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
                descriptor.close();

                m.prepare();
                m.setVolume(1f, 1f);
                m.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


}


}
```

As you can see the audio files are part of the asset bundle, the above code plays the first audio file, the second (word.getFreSound()) should then be played apart the first has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Take an New ArrayList of "Word" object,And on each item click,add the word object(wrt index) to the ArrayList(Like A PLayList).Play Music(using playfile() method) by Traversing the added Object in the ArrayList.(You can Clear the List Once you go to next Activity).